# Handling nested loops in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

```
for i in range(0, (len(df) - 1)):
  min = df.loc[i, 'min']
  if min > 0:        
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
      mn = df.loc[j, 'mn']
      min = df.loc[j, 'min']
      if min < 1 :
        df.loc[i, 'col1'] = df.loc[j, 'col2'] + (j-i)* mn            
        break
```

I am new to Pyspark. I am trying to avoid using nested loops in my pyspark project. The length of df is very large and iterating over each record is taking forever because of pyspark's lazy evaluation. I am wondering if there is a way to perform the above python logic in pyspark (dataframe based api).

I have tried using pyspark transformations with window functions like lag, lead etc., but the final expected output is not an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

Use  window functions and conditional expressions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Define a window
window_spec = Window.orderBy("row_id")

# Create a new column 
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.lit(None))

# Iterate over the DataFrame 
df = df.withColumn("min_positive", F.when(F.col("min") > 0, F.col("min")))
df = df.withColumn("cumulative_mn", F.sum(F.col("mn")).over(window_spec))
df = df.withColumn("row_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

df = df.withColumn(
    "col1",
    F.when(
        F.col("min_positive").isNotNull() & (F.col("min") < 1),
        F.col("col2") + (F.col("row_id") - F.first(F.col("row_id")).over(window_spec)) * F.col("cumulative_mn")
    ).otherwise(F.col("col1"))
)

df = df.drop("min_positive", "cumulative_mn", "row_id")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding so quickly! But the output is still not matching. The new col1 is all nulls with the above logic. I am wondering if we are even addressing the j starting from i+1 scenario at all? Also, the F.first() considers the entire dataset and not the subset of rows after min_positive not null. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.